# My terminal shows only a blank screen--How can it?

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10. in the process of editing bash.bashrc file something went wrong and all of a sudden all i'm getting when I open my terminal is a blank screen. No directory names or $. So I can't execute any commands to update, install, fix or anything. All the help out I come across assume I can use the command line. 
.
Anyone knows how to fix this? or how maybe how I can recover the default bashrc file (without using the command line)? Is my only option uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu? I don't even know how to do that without the command line.

Answer (score 3):

[rajagenupula's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/391952/449) would do the job... If you could get to a terminal. The problem is your default shell is bash (even in a TTY) so you're going to struggle to run those commands.

To get a working console, I'd press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run:

```
xterm -e sh
```

That *should* drop you into a nasty super-basic shell. And from there you can fix/rescue/etc your `.bashrc` using nano (to edit) or rajagenupula's suggested commands, which should also work (you could skip the source and just go back to your traditional terminal.

---

If you don't have graphical access, you could drop into recovery mode (using Grub at boot), run `mount -o remount,rw /` and then fix/replace the file.

Comment: I was able to get to that xterm shell following your instructions. I re-editied the bash.bashrc file and saved it. but the terminal is still blank. any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No Problem , you can restore it easily.

Just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> & login there

then paste as

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
source .bashrc
```

Then type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to reverse to GUI desktop.

Comment: thanks for replying. I tried CTR+ALT+F1. when I enter my password, nothing happens. where do I past the above commands? when I came back with F7, the terminal still didn't work. I appreciate your help.

Comment: In my case the second command was                  source ~/.bashrc

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 and later press Ctrl+Alt+F3 and login there. The press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to reverse to GUI desktop.