# Terminal is neither showing path nor working

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, paths, xfce4-terminal

The default terminal and the VS code Terminal are neither showing path nor working.
I have updated the system, cleared the cache, reinstalled the terminal, installed the new other terminals, and saw no error in the ~/.bashrc file even but found no solution. can you please help me out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check the orange links for images please

Comment: Are you really using Ubuntu 14.04??

Comment: Hello @ArturMeinild , Thanks for the response, sorry for that.. my version of ubuntu is 20.04.5.. can you please help me out now?

Comment: Please see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391951/my-terminal-shows-only-a-blank-screen-how-can-it

Comment: It seems this happens if any of the config files are corrupt. Please try and backup your current `~/.bashrc` and restore the default one.

Comment: Can you run `exec bash` in that terminal?

Comment: Also related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/406767/terminal-is-blank-on-second-user-account https://askubuntu.com/questions/787634/terminal-is-showing-just-blank-screen

Comment: woah!!! 
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
source .bashrc
This really worked for me, Thank you  so much @ArturMeinild for the quick help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot type anything in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454894/cannot-type-anything-in-terminal)